# Sum of the Geometrico-Factorial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

How can I find the sum of the series $$1 + x + 2!\cdot x^2 + 3!\cdot x^3 + \dots + n!\cdot x^n\quad?$$

I was solving this just out of fun but now it doesn't give away. How to form a general formula for such a series? I have been trying my might and even tried wolfram alpha but it answers me in terms of the complex gamma function and exponential integral function $(\operatorname{Ei})$. Is there a simpler formula and if not how can I derive this huge thing?

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html

Comment: Use MathJax to make your question readable and clear.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I've edited this question for you. Please check that I didn't inadvertently chenge your meaning, and do use MathJax in the future :)

Comment: I see that you've edited your question again. Please note that your edit puts the mathematics in a non-MathJax state that makes more difficult to read, without apparently changing anything material. You might want to revert the changes.

Comment: Thanks Devashish ......I have not yet learnt to use mathjax....I will sure try to use it in future! :)

Answer (score 0):

The series $\sum n! x^n$ is divergent when $x\neq 0$.

Littlewood wrote (in the preface for Hardy's book "Divergent series"):

> "... Abel wrote in 1828: "Divergent series are the invention of the devil and it is shameful to base on them any demonstration whatsoever". In the ensuing period of critical revision they were simply rejected. Then came a time when it was found that something after all could be done about them ..."

You will find some ideas on the sum of the series  $\ \sum  n! (-x)^n\ $ in [the book "Divergent series" written by Hardy](https:///sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/335_17/Hardy-DivergentSeries%202.pdf) (p 26-29).

Comment: Thanks for that...appreciate it...I will check it out!

Comment: Any other methods or ideas guys??

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but to me, it looks like the OP is asking about finite sums, not infinite series. BTW, I've seen this series used in a doctoral theses for chemistry where the expected result was achieved  by using only the first 3 terms and dropping the rest.

Comment: I agree, is it possible to address summing up to $n$ as indicated in the question?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Could you please link the reference, it would be helpful!

Comment: @QuasiVinci : No. and no. No because that reasoning back then was absolute nonsense. Second no because it was on paper and internet was not what it is today, more like email exchange and newsgroups. And  even if not, I wouldn't sneak on someone.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Okay, I understand. Thanks anyways..Appreciate your help!